# Are these interchangeable?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

He's not here. Can I take a message?

He's not here. Can I get a message?

Are these two sentences 'Can I take a message?/Can I get a message?' interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

"Can I get a message?" is understandable (and is equivalent in meaning to "Can I take a message?"), but it is not idiomatic English. For that reason, it is probably best to avoid using it.